# adding multiple rows in df based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

in my df i want to add row when its meets specific condition,df has thousands of rows.In id column when a new value of id is started i want to add new row copying same id value. df is as as below

```html
id                        name                              value
0000                    length                                46
0000                    status                              completed
0000                    segment                              21
1111                     tp                                 0.1
1111                     x                                  56
2222                     point                              23.01
2222                     x                                  50
2222                     y                                  40
```

expected output is

```html
     id                        name                              value
    0000                       type                                description #new row
    0000                    length                                46
    0000                    status                              completed
    0000                    segment                               21
    1111                       type                               description  #new row
    1111                     tp                                   0.1
    1111                     x                                    56
    2222                     type                                description  #new row
    2222                     point                                23.01
    2222                     x                                    50
    2222                     y                                    40
```

i know about loc[] or iloc[] but i can not use them as i dont know the exact index or position.I am new to pandas. Is there a way to do it? any help will be ppreciated

Comment: whats the condition?

Comment: condition is that when new id is started means 0000 switch to 1111 then before switching to 1111 add new row where id is 1111 and name is type

Answer (score 2):

```
new = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first().assign(name='type', value='description  #new row')
df = pd.concat([new, df]).sort_values('id')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     id     name                  value
0  0000     type  description  #new row
0  0000   length                     46
1  0000   status              completed
2  0000  segment                     21
1  1111     type  description  #new row
3  1111       tp                    0.1
4  1111        x                     56
2  2222     type  description  #new row
5  2222    point                  23.01
6  2222        x                     50
7  2222        y                     40
```

Note: this assumes that column `id` is sorted before.

Comment: it work fine for  first row but then it add new row at end of id and some time it add same id row twice. how to fix it?

Comment: @user19 Before running this code, try to sort column `id`, e.g `df = df.sort_values('id').reset_index()`

Comment: I already tried it I mean id column is sorted but still same problem